# Datetime format to "\/Date(1213131)\/"

Tags: apex, json, datetime

I'm trying to call a Webservice with a DateTime format like this : `"\/Date(x)\/"` where `x` is the millisecond value since 1970.

How can I generate a DateTime in this format?

Here is what i've done :

```
dateValidation_long = dateValidation_string.getTime();
String a = '\\/Date(';
String b = ')\\/';
modifierEntiteDeFacturation3C_request.dateValidation = a + dateValidation_long + b;
```

Here is the result in my console :

```
\/Date(1505904139000)\/
```

Then, i'm trying to JSON.serialize this date, to send it via a Webservice, and this is the result :

```
dateValidation":"\\/Date(1505904534000)\\/"
```

The webservice response is not OK because the format is different as expected :

```
DateTime content '\/Date(1505904139000)\/' does not start with '\/Date(' and end with ')\/' as required for JSON.
```

Comment: We need more information : what error do you get ? which pattern is the right one : "/Date(x)/" OR "\/Date(x)\/" ?

Comment: if i'm not escaping this is my error : 

    Illegal string literal: Invalid string literal '\/Date('. Illegal character sequence \/' in string literal.

Comment: Putting a backslash as an expected pattern whereas it has an escaping behavior in several technologies/languages/whatever........... Backslash has 92 as ASCII code character, try concatenating it without escaping the backslash when you declare String a and b

Comment: @Answers_Seeker I agree with you with this horrible pattern... Even the DateTime format in millisecond for a date... #nocomment
But, finally, I found a "crappy" workaround :
envelop = envelop.replace('\\\\', '\\'); (After the JSON.Serialize)

Comment: could you post an answer with your workaround, this could help other users facing similar issues in the future. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make my code working, here is what i've done :

```
String envelop     = JSON.serialize(modifierEntiteDeFacturation3C_request);
envelop = envelop.replace('\\\\', '\\');
```

Before : `dateValidation":"\\/Date(1505904534000)\\/"`

After `dateValidation":"\/Date(1505904534000)\/"`